# My jersey service application shows Class not found exception. But i have configured these dependancy in my pom file

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, jersey

[image: Here is my project structure]

> Error like this:-  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)

It will work when I put all jar files under lib (WEB-INF/lib) folder.But I want pom file to solve this.

Comment: Here is my pom dependency

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: edit your question and add this in the question body, not in comment

Comment: First of all this question is a duplicate of yours [36329382](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329382). Then, please add your pom.xml (relevant parts) and your web.xml (complete) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about your configuration resp. **pom.xml** and incomplete tutorials. If you want your pom.xml to solve this for you, you need to add a few things.

#### Plugins

First things first. The little red cross and the fact, that your project is configured to run under Java 1.5 lets me guess, that you have compatibility issues with your deps. Especialy with `javax.ws.rs \ javax.ws.rs-api`.

To solve this, you may want maven handle it by the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, you possibly want to run the server "in" eclipse. Here you can use the [tomcat7-maven-plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The last plugin to use is the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

#### Jersey Dependencies

To start with Jersey you just need to configure a single dep:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

**I need to say, that there are [newer versions available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey), but you might have reasons to use 1.19**

Your complete pom.xml should now look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sujith</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</project.maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <project.tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>2.2</project.tomcat7-maven-plugin.version>
        <project.maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</project.maven-war-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.tomcat7-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

In Eclipse you now right click your project and select -> Run As / Debug As -> Maven build...

In the **Edit configuration and lauch** menu, you now add the goal: `clean install tomcat7:run-war` and that's it.

Your server should start and the resource is available under 
`http://127.0.0.1:8080` / `{web.xml\servlet-mapping\url-pattern}` / `{path-to-resource}`

One last thing. Please check out the original examples first. Most of the tutorial out there are crap. And finally, pls read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages.

Have a nice day.